# Expectation-Maximisation derivations

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I've come across a few different sources on expectation-maximisation which I can't quite match up.

The CS229 lecture 8 [1] states that the function we must write down and maximise is:

$$
Q_1 = \sum_{i}\sum_{z_i}p(z_i|x_i, \theta)\log\frac{p(x_i, z_i| \theta)}{p(z_i|x_i, \theta)}
$$

Which we can write as an expectation

$$
Q_1 = \sum_{i}\mathbb{E}_{p(z_i|x_i, \theta)}\left[\log\frac{p(x_i, z_i| \theta)}{p(z_i|x_i, \theta)}\right]
$$

Other sources including Tanner's book [2], Bishop's book [3] and the Probabilistic Perspective book [4] state the $Q$ function as:

$$
Q_2 = \sum_{i}\mathbb{E}_{p(z_i|x_i, \theta)}\left[p(\theta| x_i, z_i)\right].
$$

Both sources agree that the expectation is taken over the $z$'s posterior distribution but the arguments in the log are different.  I've tried applying Baye's rule to the term in the log in $Q_2$ which gives

$$
p(\theta| x_i, z_i) = \frac{p(x_i, z_i | \theta)p(\theta)}{p(x_z, z_i)}.
$$

This has the $p(x_i, z_i | \theta)$ term we want in the numerator but the rest doesn't work.

What am I missing, is it something to do with the expectation being conditional on $x_i$ and $\theta$?

[1] http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf

[2] https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387946887

[3] http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf

[4] https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/